# sp_rda_reauthorize_db not creating remote database copy

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

I have a db which is stretch enabled in SQL server 2016 RC3.

I took local backup of that database, and restored successfully. As we know that after restore the link to Azure SQL Server will get break, therefore I am using the below mention T-SQL to resume the connectivity, additionally I am specifying @with_copy = 1, so that it create a copy of database in Azure SQL server.  But below mention T-SQL always fails with error as

*Copying remote database 'RDADB_A40A50B5B-386A-42C4-B19C-3C2516172CAF' to remote database 'RDADB_A_Clone74FF1F31-A689-4866-BDD1-F90D15C157BB'.
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "stretchserver-sc-server-dbstrech-20160314-114758814.database.windows.net" returned message "Query timeout expired".
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_rda_reauthorize_db, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 5]
The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "stretchserver-sc-server-dbstrech-20160314-114758814.database.windows.net" reported an error. Execution terminated by the provider because a resource limit was reached.
Msg 7320, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_rda_reauthorize_db, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 5]
Cannot execute the query "CREATE DATABASE [RDADB_A_Clone74FF1F31-A689-4866-BDD1-F90D15C157BB] AS COPY OF [RDADB_A40A50B5B-386A-42C4-B19C-3C2516172CAF]" against OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "stretchserver-sc-server-dbstrech-20160314-114758814.database.windows.net".*

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL  AzureCred WITH IDENTITY = 'AzureAdministrator',

SECRET = '****' Declare @credentialName nvarchar(128);

SET @credentialName = N'AzureCred';

EXEC sp_rda_reauthorize_db @credential = @credentialName, @with_copy = 1

**Note :- I have configured the firewall of Azure SQL server to include my IP.**

Comment: What version (CTP/RC??) are you running? Also, what else is running on your server in Azure? Looks like you're potentially hitting 2 separate issues so details will be helpful. If you login to the Azure portal, do you get any messages from the Notification service (the little bell thing near the top right corner)?

Comment: No I am not getting any notification when I login to Azure. I am using RC3 SQL 2016.   things were working fine with the same above T-SQL command when I was using CTP3.2 SQL 2016.  looks like something is breaking in RC3

Answer (score 0):

The create copy part is a regression. I believe the fix is still being worked on. Please file a bug on https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ if you want to track its progress. In the meantime, you can set the option to 0 or false to avoid creating a copy. If you do need to make copies, let us know what your scenario is and we'll see if we can find you temporary workarounds.

Comment: Is there any update on this issue fix from Microsoft?